# Possible to initialize all UI elements in one method?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to initialize all UI elements of certain type (like all TextViews or all LineraLayouts or ...) in a some kind of loop?

I have many layouts with a lot of the elements of the same type and it's really painful to do it all just by typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RoboGuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) .It doesn't use loops, but helps you to Inject your View, Resource, System Service, or any other object in to your code.

`RoboGuice` is a framework that brings the simplicity and ease of Dependency Injection to Android, using Google's own Guice library.

To give you an idea, take a look at this simple example of a typical Android activity:

```
class AndroidWay extends Activity { 
TextView name; 
ImageView thumbnail; 
LocationManager loc; 
Drawable icon; 
String myName; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    name      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name); 
    thumbnail = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail); 
    loc       = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    icon      = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon); 
    myName    = getString(R.string.app_name); 
    name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
} 
}
```

This example is 19 lines of code. If you're trying to read through onCreate(), you have to skip over 5 lines of boilerplate initialization to find the only one that really matters: name.setText(). And complex activities can end up with a lot more of this sort of initialization code.

Compare this to the same app, written using RoboGuice:

```
class RoboWay extends RoboActivity { 
@InjectView(R.id.name)             TextView name; 
@InjectView(R.id.thumbnail)        ImageView thumbnail; 
@InjectResource(R.drawable.icon)   Drawable icon; 
@InjectResource(R.string.app_name) String myName; 
@Inject                            LocationManager loc; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
} 
}
```

In this example, onCreate() is much easier to take in at a glance. All the platform boilerplate is stripped away and you're left with just your own app's business logic. Do you need a SystemService? Inject one. Do you need a View or Resource? Inject those, too, and RoboGuice will take care of the details.

RoboGuice's goal is to make your code be about your app, rather than be about all the initialization and lifecycle code you typically have to maintain in Android.

This text is from [here](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/SimpleExample)

Comment: WOW this looks GREAT! Have you used it? Are there any bugs? Does this additional layer slow down the app?

Comment: hi. sorry but I havent used it in my production app as I read about Roboguice only 2 weeks back. I am planning to use it when i jump back to android dev very soon.

Comment: It really looks promising, but I am afraid to use it in my current project. I will first try it in my private projects, although from the Wiki notes, it seems that it's rather stable for most of project of medium complexity.

Comment: Yes exactly, It seems stable, and many apps use it. I wouldnt hesitate to use it in my production app if it works well in my personal projects

Comment: If not better answer appears, I will mark this as answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I have/had done something similar. Just for your reference, here's the code:

```
public class AbcActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected boolean changesPending;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
        setViews(); //this method is created and called to take care of the buttons and edittext fields, and can probably hold a number of other fields/widgets as well
    }

    /** Take care of the Buttons and EditTexts here*/
    private void setViews() 
    {
        EditText userEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText passwordEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                login(); // some random method
            }
        });

        Button cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                cancel(); //another random method
            }
        });

        userEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            {
                changesPending = true;
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });

        passwordEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
        {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            {
                changesPending = true;
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to handle a large number of `View`s it may be worthwhile handling creation of these `View`s at runtime, attaching them to the relevant container. For example:

```
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TEXT_VIEWS; i++){
        TextView tv = new TextView(this); // where 'this' is your Activity
        tv.setText("This is TextView " + i);
        container.addView(tv);
    }
```

Properties set in your xml file for a `View` usually have a corresponding Java method call.